# Depletion Mosfet as current source to power load

Tags: power, mosfet, current-source, discharge

I came acros the following application note for a Depletion Mosfet (https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application_Note_Applications_for_Depletion_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf) and i got intrigued.
[image: Depletion Mosfet as current source]

In the above image, the depletion mosfet is being used as a current source to power a load with a constant current (the best it can, since this type of current source as some oscilations in the output current - from what i read).

My question is, how can you calculate the power that is being dissipated in the depletion mosfet (couldn't find the answer from my search)? It's Vds*Ids?

The objective would be to use the depletion mosfet + a power resistor to dissipate the energy from a set of capacitors (constant current discharge). The objective is that the depletion mosfet dissipates the less possible and that the resistor (load) dissipates the energy.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, the power dissipated in the MOSFET is Vds * Ids. Assuming that it behaves as a current limiter, the voltage on the resistor would be limited, so limiting the resistor dissipation. At higher voltages than this, the MOSFET would dissipate more power.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. That would be the thing to avoid, the resistor (load) should be the one dissipating that energy,